# Python can't list my directory

Tags: python, file, operating-system, directory, bottle

I have this code in my [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org) app to list a directory full of files:

```
[Post(name[:-3]) for name in os.listdir("posts")]
```

On my local computer, it's fine. But on my server I am consistently getting this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'posts'
```

`os.listdir('.')` and `$ ls` reports that the directory is there. `os.getcwd()` reports that I'm in the parent directory and should be able to access it. `glob.glob("posts/*.md")` returns nothing, so I don't think it's a problem with `listdir`. Running `python` over ssh and trying the same code is successful (ie: I get a list of `Post` objects).

Is there something I've missed?

### Edit

Thanks for all the advice. The source of the problem was WSGI misconfiguration. I've since re-mounted the application using the proper config arguments, and all is well.

Comment: When you're getting the `OSError`, is your script running under your user account or some other account?

Comment: Can you post the output you get when you prepend `listdir` with `import subprocess;subprocess.call(['ls', '-l', '.'])` ? My first guess is that the directory is capitalized differently on the server.

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x 2 smalone smalone   4096 Aug 26 05:35 posts`, and I'm not sure if it runs as my user account or something else. How can I find out?

Comment: @Stevo M. That output is as expected. However, I wanted the full output, and from the exact same Python script  that's running into the problem. That's not to spite you or anything, but to exclude mistakes such as a trailing space, insufficient permissions (obviously not the case here, since you wouldn't have gotten that error), etc. You can find out which user you are with `subprocess.call(['id'])` in the Python script (or [`os.getresuid`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getresuid) ).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is permissions -- make sure that your permissions are set so that the app has at least read access. `listdir` will still say that something exists, even if it can't read it.

Next thought is that looks like a relative path -- are you sure that the relative path is correct? I know that you've found the directory through `listdir('.')` (so it shouldn't matter), but what happens if you actually hard code the full path to the directory? (there are plenty of times where "it shouldn't matter" does)

Comment: The directory has read access, and using the full path (both manually and with `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'posts')` has no success.

Comment: If you call listdir on a linux/unix system, I think you also need Execute permission to list content